# Redis: How to intersect a "normal" set with a sorted set?

Tags: redis

Assume I have a set (or sorted set or list if that would be better) **A** of 100 to 1000 strings.

Then I have a sorted set **B** of many more strings, say one million.

Now **C** should be the intersection of **A** and **B** (of the strings of course).

I want to have every tuple (X, SCORE_OF_X_IN_B) where X is in **C**.

Any Idea?

I got two ideas:

1. Interstore

   - store A a sorted set with every score being 0
   - interstore to D
   - get every item of D
   - delete D
2. Simple loop in client

   - loop over A in my client programm
   - get zscore for every string

While 1. has way too much overhead on the redis side (Has to write for example. The redis page states quite a high time complexity, too http://redis.io/commands/zinterstore), 2. would have |A| database connections and won't be a good choice.

Maybe I could write a redis/lua script which will work like zscore but with an arbitrary number of strings, but I'm not sure if my hoster allows scripts...

So I just wanted to ask SO, if there is an elegant and fast solution available without scripting!

Comment: In option 1, wouldn't D be no bigger than A? In that case, the write that you're avoiding would be small, unless the strings in A are large (and if they are then B would likely be really huge). Darn. I just realized this question is 10 years old.

Answer (score 43):

There is a simple solution to your problem: `ZINTERSTORE` will work with a `SET` and a `ZSET`. Try:

```
redis> sadd foo a
(integer) 1
redis> zadd bar 1 a
(integer) 1
redis> zadd bar 2 b
(integer) 1
redis> zinterstore baz 2 foo bar AGGREGATE MAX
(integer) 1
redis> zrange baz 0 -1 withscores
1) "a"
2) "1"
```

**Edit:** I added `AGGREGATE MAX` above, since redis will give each member of the (non-sorted) set `foo` a default score of `1`, and `SUM` that with whatever score it has in the (sorted) set `bar`.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I have written in my question (see above, point 1). I also have written that I judge this solution as too slow. Note I asked for an elegant and fast solution, not a simple one! Didn't know you could do a direct zinterstore with a set and a sorted set though. Thanks for your answer and sorry for obviously choosing a bad headline...