# Is a zinterstore going to be faster/slower when one of the two input sets is a normal set?

Tags: performance, redis

I know I can do a zinterstore with a normal set as an argument ([Redis: How to intersect a "normal" set with a sorted set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10500695/redis-how-to-intersect-a-normal-set-with-a-sorted-set)). Is that going to affect performance? Is it going to be faster/slower than working only with zsets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [sorted-set source code](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/t_zset.c), `ZINTERSTORE` will treat a set like a sorted-set with score 1, the function name is zunionInterGenericCommand.

Intersecting sets will take more or less time depending on  the sorting algorithm used in this step, for example:

```
   /* sort sets from the smallest to largest, this will improve our
     * algorithm's performance */
    qsort(src,setnum,sizeof(zsetopsrc),zuiCompareByCardinality);
```

There are also differences in how Sets and Zsets are stored, which will affect how they are read. Redis will decide how to encode a (Sorted) Set depending on how many elements they contain. Therefore iterating through them requires different work.

However for any practical purposes, I'd say that your best bet is to use `ZINTERSTORE`, and I'll explain why: I hardly see how anything you might write in your source code will beat Redis performance when doing the intersection you want to do.

If your concern is performance, you're getting too much in the details. Your focus should be in the big-O of the operation instead, shown in the command [documentation](https://redis.io/commands/zinterstore):

> Time complexity: O(N*K)+O(M*log(M)) worst case with N being the
>   smallest input sorted set, K being the number of input sorted sets and
>   M being the number of elements in the resulting sorted set.

What this tells you is:
1-The size of the smaller set and the amount of sets you plan to intersect determine the first part. Therefore if you know that you'll always intersect 2 sets, one being small and the other one being huge; then you can say that the first part is constant. A good example of this would be intersect a set of all available products in a store (where the score is how many in stock), and a sorted set of products in a user's cart.

In this case you'll have only 2 sets, and you'll know one of them will be very small.

2-The size of the resulting sorted set M can cause a big performance issue. But there's a trick here: big sorted sets are encoded as a skip list when they are too big. A small sorted set will be stored as a zip list, which can cause an important hit in big sorted sets.

However, for the case of intersection, you know that the resulting set can not be bigger than the smaller set you provide. For a union, the resulting set will contain all elements in all sets; so attention needs to be on the size of the bigger sets more than on the smallest.

In summary, the answer to the question of performance with (sorted) sets is: it depends on the sizes of the sets much more than in the actual datatype. Take into consideration that the resulting data structure will be a sorted set regardless of all the inputs being sets. Therefore a big sorted set will be stored (less efficiently) as a skip list.

Knowing beforehand how many sets you plan to intersect (2, 3, depending on user input?) and the size of the smaller set (10? hundreds? thousands?) will give you a much better idea than the internal datatypes. The algorithm for intersecting is the same for both types.

Comment: The question is simply asking if the datatype is different whether or not it will affect the performance. But the answer focuses on big-O. I think the answer is kinda off topic.

Answer (score 1):

Redis by default assumes the normal set to have some default score for each element, therefore it treats the normal set to be like a sorted set with all elements having an equal default score. I believe performance should be the same as intersecting 2 sorted sets.

Comment: Do you have a source?

Comment: Try making a set with elements {a,b} and a sorted set with elements {a,b} and scores {1,2} respectively. Now try zinterstore with an AGGREGATE SUM and you would see that redis by default assigned a default value to all elements of the normal set

Comment: That is not my question. Of course that is the way redis does it. I am wondering whether the memory usage of zsets and sets is similar. And whether combining them in a zinterstore is slower/faster than working only with zsets.